# Next.js: `onSubmit` not executing callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js

In my Next.js module, I have a form declared as follows:

```
<form onSubmit = {() => {
async() => await getCertificate(id)
.then(async resp => await resp.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.error(err))
console.log("getCertificate completed")
}}>
```

Function `getCertificate()` is defined in the same `.tsx` file as:

```
async function getCertificate(id: string) : Promise<Response> {
  console.log("in getCertificate")
  const resp = await fetch(`${serverUri}/certs/${id}`)
  console.log(`Response data: ${await resp.json()}`)
  return resp
}
```

It appears that `getCertificate()` is not getting called at all.  While the final `console.log("getCertificate completed")` inside my `onSubmit` handler is executing correctly, none of the `console.log()` statements insisde `getCertificate()` are being executed.

No errors are being thrown or logged to the console.  The only thing appearing in the console (in addition to `getCertificate completed`), is `Navigated to http://localhost:3000/?certId=my_cert_id`.

Any idea why it is behaving like this?

(The only other things to note are that my `.tsx` file is decorated with `'use client'` since I am utilizing a client library for certain other functionalities, and that my form definition is inside the `return` statement of an `export default function`.  Everything else works as expected except for `getCertificates()` not being hit).

Comment: The way you’re composing async/await and blending promise.then in is really strange. Stick to one strategy or the other.

Comment: Can you make a link to GitHub where I can see a complete example, that will be easy to reproduce? At the moment I don't see how to reproduce the form's receiver page, and also these code fragments does not look like minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possible solution

If the only problem is to get `getCertificate` executed, then you may try to do something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const serverUri = "http://myserver.com";

export default function Certificate() {
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  async function getCertificate(id: string): Promise<Response> {
    console.log("in getCertificate");
    const resp = await fetch(`${serverUri}/certs/${id}`);
    console.log(`Response data: ${await resp.json()}`);
    return resp;
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={async (event: any) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      try {
        const response = await getCertificate(id);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      console.log("getCertificate completed");
    }}>
      <label>
        Certificate ID:
        <input type="text" value={id} onChange={e => setId(e.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: execution result]

As you can see on screenshot, `in getCertificate` is printed to console.

### The reason why it fails to execute

Let's looks closer at the original function:

```
() => {
    async() => await getCertificate(id)
    .then(async resp => await resp.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    console.log("getCertificate completed")
}
```

As you may see here, you just define an anonymous async arrow function here (without assignment of that function to any variable, thus this function is never called) and then just execute `console.log`. So the `console.log` is the only thing that is actually executed.

Also, you add `await` before call to `getCertificate`, it is not required and may lead to additional confusion.

#### Let's simplify this code line

```
async() => await getCertificate(id)
.then(async resp => await resp.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.error(err))
```

So first we will reformat the code to see the structure:

```
async() => { 
    await getCertificate(id)
        .then(async resp => await resp.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
```

Then we remove unnecessary function definition:

```
await getCertificate(id)
    .then(async resp => await resp.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Then we will remove unnecessary `await`:

```
getCertificate(id)
    .then(async resp => await resp.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

### Another solution

So using transformations in previous section we can get another way to define the whole function.

```
(event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    getCertificate(id)
        .then(async resp => await resp.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .then(() => console.log("getCertificate completed with no errors"))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
        .then(() => console.log("getCertificate completed with errors"))
}
```

### P.S.

Note that `event.preventDefault()` in both solutions will block actual transmission of form data, and will force handling everything in JS instead. It is optional and may be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

You wrap your `getCertificate` call within an anonymous function that you never actually call. From the looks of it, there is no need for that wrapper function at all, so you can just move its internal logic up a level into the `onSubmit` function directly, like this:

```
<form onSubmit = {async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await getCertificate(id);
        const data = await resp.json();
        console.log(data);
        console.log("getCertificate completed");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}}>
```

or using promise chaining:

```
<form onSubmit = {() => {
    getCertificate(id)
        .then(async resp => await resp.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .then(() => console.log("getCertificate completed"))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
}}>
```

And I'd recommend you stick to either `async`/`await` or promise chaining rather than mixing them as mixing makes the logic a bit harder to follow. Personally, I recommend `async`/`await`.